# Building Mapbox in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, mapbox, unity-webgl

I don't know if this has already been asked but I am trying to build an app in unity using the Mapbox SDK. The problem is that when I try building it in a WebGL format, then it says this:

"Build completed with a result of 'Failed'
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/IMGUI/GUIUtility.cs:179)"

Does anyone if Mapbox supports building in WebGL and if not, what another way can I use to share my app as an online game?
I hope this is enough info. Please try and make it simple, I don't know much about this kind of stuff.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

WebGL is still under preview and alot of things don't work in it, to share your game over the web you could build as Windows application, then zip the output folder, put it in a github repo and link the repo to people you want to share your game to. If its a mobile game you can build as an APK and share you apk via github as well. Of course there is other options too but just to give you some ideas.

Comment: But all my friends have Macs, so i just want to be able to share it over the web. If I build it in a  Facebook thing, can i embed it in a website?

Answer (score 0):

From below 2 posts, it appears that in order to build it on WebGL, you would have to get rid of the AR folders and files.

- https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/7531
- https://medium.com/@jonathanwitcoski/day-20-making-a-webgl-game-in-unity-with-mapbox-sdk-31aeb147df15